# Unhandled exception has occurred in your application C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I am getting this error when I run my c# program for about 30 mins:
[IMAGE LINK](https://www.dropbox.com/s/3euos0cfaf0pum7/20150416_070119.jpg?dl=0)

This is what the Details box contains:

```html
See the end of this message for details on invoking 
just-in-time (JIT) debugging instead of this dialog box.

****** Exception Text ******
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
at WindowsFormsApplication1.Form1.button6_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
at WindowsFormsApplication1.Form1.button7_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
at WindowsFormsApplication1.Form1.timer2_Tick(Object sender, EventArgs e)
at System.Windows.Forms.Timer.OnTick(EventArgs e)
at System.Windows.Forms.Timer.TimerNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)

****** Loaded Assemblies ******
mscorlib
Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.34014 built by: FX45W81RTMGDR
CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework/v4.0.30319/mscorlib.dll
------
instagram Robot
Assembly Version: 1.0.0.0
Win32 Version: 1.0.0.0
CodeBase: file:///C:/Users/kingd_000/Desktop/Instagram%20Robot/Instagram%20Robot/instagram%20Robot.exe
------
System.Windows.Forms
Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.33440 built by: FX45W81RTMREL
CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Windows.Forms/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Windows.Forms.dll
------
System.Drawing
Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.33440 built by: FX45W81RTMREL
CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Drawing/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Drawing.dll
------
System
Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.34239 built by: FX452RTMGDR
CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.dll
------
SKGL
Assembly Version: 2.0.4.1
Win32 Version: 2.0.4.1
CodeBase: file:///C:/Users/kingd_000/Desktop/Instagram%20Robot/Instagram%20Robot/SKGL.DLL
------
Microsoft.VisualBasic
Assembly Version: 10.0.0.0
Win32 Version: 12.0.20806.33440 built by: FX45W81RTMREL
CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/Microsoft.VisualBasic/v4.0_10.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll
------
System.Core
Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.33440 built by: FX45W81RTMREL
CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Core/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Core.dll
------
System.Xml
Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.34230 built by: FX452RTMGDR
CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Xml/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Xml.dll
------
Microsoft.mshtml
Assembly Version: 7.0.3300.0
Win32 Version: 7.0.3300.0
CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/assembly/GAC/Microsoft.mshtml/7.0.3300.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/Microsoft.mshtml.dll
------

****** JIT Debugging ******
To enable just-in-time (JIT) debugging, the .config file for this
application or computer (machine.config) must have the
jitDebugging value set in the system.windows.forms section.
The application must also be compiled with debugging
enabled.

For example:

<configuration>
<system.windows.forms jitDebugging="true" />
</configuration>

When JIT debugging is enabled, any unhandled exception
will be sent to the JIT debugger registered on the computer
rather than be handled by this dialog box.
```

I have no idea how to fix this problem and am hoping someone here will be able to find out how to fix this problem. 
Thanks in Advance!

Comment: This forum isn't set up for step-by-step assisted debugging. Try restating your problem as a question that can be answered. Voting to close.

Comment: Look in button6_click and see what pointer(s) you are using.  Without seeing the code we have no hope of telling you exactly what's wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Debug -> Exceptions and tick all of the exception boxes on "thrown".  The debugger should break at the point in the program the exception is thrown and from there you can work out what's causing it.